# Can the tag wikis for the mandatory tags and moderator-only tags be propagated to all the other meta sites?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, meta, tag-wiki, per-site-meta

A question was raised on <strike>NothingToInstall's</strike> Web Apps chat about [missing tag wiki's for `[status-completed]`](http://chat.webapps.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/624#624) etc.

I went and created some, but realised that these would be the same for all meta sites, plus there's the `[featured]` tag and the mandatory tags. At which point I thought there must be a better way.

So can the tag wiki's for these be propagated out to all the site specific metas? It would save a lot of duplicated effort and also possible misinformation if the person creating the local copy got something wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most of this came from [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/47634/how-does-meta-stack-overflow-work/47640#47640) (as I originally wrote it anyway), but I did some additional editing. Once this is finalized, it should probably be copied back into that question.

Just having excerpts for the `[status-*]` tags are probably sufficient... I think I've described them well enough in that amount of space, and there are no instructions to give to users since they can't tag with those anyway.

---

### bug

Excerpt

Indicates you've found an erroneous or unexpected behaviour in the system that needs to be fixed.

Body

When reporting a bug, your question should include what you did to discover the bug, the steps required to reproduce the problem, the given system output, and the expected system output. If necessary to document or explain the issue, please include a screenshot.

### feature-request

Excerpt

You have an idea for a new feature, or for a change to the existing functionality.

Body

Your question should contain the details of your proposal, including a justification of why the new feature is needed and/or how it can improve the community. Basically, prove to the administration that they should spend time developing your feature.

### discussion

Excerpt

The question you're asking is designed to solicit opinions or best-practices on a particular topic, with the goal of reaching community consensus.

Body

Discussion questions are the heart of your community. For example: Should a certain question be allowed on the site? For what reason did a moderator lock a certain question? Are said actions setting a precedent? Be sure to present your entire case and background information/data so the subject can be discussed fully.

### support

Excerpt

You need help with the use of one or more of the site's features.

Body

Before posting your question, please check the [FAQs](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/faq), and do a [search](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/search) to see if your problem already has a known solution or procedure. If you cannot find an answer, we will be happy to help you.

### faq

Excerpt

These questions are the most frequently asked and answered questions on Meta.

Body

Before posting your own question, please consult these questions to see if there is already an answer that solves your problem.

### status-completed

Excerpt

Indicates that a feature request has been implemented, a bug has been fixed, or another type of request has been processed.

### status-declined

Excerpt

Indicates that a request (usually a feature request) has been considered, but will not be implemented. Generally speaking, a developer will leave a comment as to why, or the community will come to consensus that the request is unnecessary.

### status-bydesign

Excerpt

Indicates that a submitted issue is actually due to the existing design of the system and is not considered erroneous behaviour.

### status-norepro

Excerpt

Indicates that erroneous reported behavior cannot be reproduced by the developers, or can no longer be reproduced by anyone.

### status-reproduced

Excerpt

Indicates that the symptoms of a bug report have been reproduced by the developers, and an action decision is pending.

### status-planned

Excerpt

Indicates that a change in functionality has been considered and received positively, and work on it is either in progress, or will begin soon.

### status-deferred

Excerpt

Indicates that the issue will be reviewed in the future, or that a change in functionality is being delayed until a future date.

### status-review

Indicates that a change in functionality is currently under consideration, or needs further investigation.

### featured

Excerpt

A special moderator-only tag to mark important meta discussions. A question with this tag can be seen on the parent site in a special sidebar in the questions list and when viewing individual questions.

Body

This tag is meant to highlight important discussions and attract attention to them. These can be recent events, site definitions, and any discussion whose resolution may have a critical impact on the whole site. It is generally a wise idea to at least look at any new questions with this tag.

(stolen from Gaming)

Comment: I like this, I upvoted this, but we still need a few more post bodies here ...

Comment: @waffles: Do we really need post bodies for all the `[status-*]` tags?

Comment: .. need no ... but it would be nice cause otherwise the wiki page looks pretty ugly. I will use this as a starting point.

Comment: @waffles: Okay. I'll come back to this when I have more time.

Answer (score 4):

<strike>This is totally approved, however it is also totally deferred until all the mandatory and status tag wikis are in a **consistent** state on meta that does not include [inside jokes](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/bug/info), which would only cause lots of confusion on the per site metas.</strike>

In fact, Jeff told me to do this now, I am wiring it all up but deferring till we have consistent wikis on meta.

<sup>If you are unhappy with this decision, take it up with [shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/62907/revisions)</sup>

Completed in dev, awaiting deploy.. special thanks to Jon Seigel.

Comment: Hey man, no one else cared enough to write them...

Comment: @shog I follow, and on meta its kind of amusing, I just find it odd that people want me to copy them in their current state

Comment: @waffles: You might want to [help us out](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/status-reproduced/topusers) by temporarily disabling the upvote requirement... I have nearly 20k rep but I can still only edit the wikis of the top 3 tags.

Comment: @Jon, just post it as an answer here ... I need to copy the markdown anyway to another place.

Comment: @waffles: Done.

Comment: Has this been pushed out to all sites? I checked on webapps and the wiki entries are still those I created.

Comment: Pushed out but no source was provided for featured. Missed it

Comment: @waffles: Thanks! Should these have overwritten existing content? I looked at meta.superuser and it retained the existing excerpts and descriptions.

Comment: @Jon nope, I did not delete any old wikis, you can always overwrite our defaults, the defaults are just ... hmmm ... defaults

Answer (score 0):

Here are nice wiki excerpts and bodies for all the required tags.

### bug

Exerpt

This is the exerpt

Body

This is the body

### feature-request

### discussion

### faq

### status-completed

### status-declined

### status-bydesign

### status-norepro

### status-reproduced

### status-planned

### status-deferred

### status-review

### support

Comment: Missing "featured" for the new sites.

Comment: @chrisf if you write it I'll propagate it :)

Comment: I've updated Jon's answer with the wiki "stolen" from Gaming's meta.