# How do tag wikis work on private beta metas?

Tags: support, tag-wiki, per-site-meta

I am participating in a private beta, and on meta I asked a [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) question. I wanted to make sure other users knew they could add the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag to propose questions to be tagged [faq](/questions/tagged/faq), so I went to the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag wiki and saw:

> All registered users may propose new tag wikis

But no instructions on how to propose it. After read [this MSO question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites) and seeing [random's](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/9314/random) answer:

> All child metas across the Stack Exchange network suck down their tag
>   wiki pages from the motherboat here on Meta Stack Overflow.
>
> > We're not currently allowing tag wikis to be edited on metas, as we plan to push out the shared meta tag wikis from meta.so.

I understand I can't create a new tag wiki on a child meta site. But why does the [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag wiki [on this private beta](https://cogsci.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/faq-proposed/info) still say:

> About [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed)
>
> There is no tag wiki for this tag … yet!
>
> Tag wikis help introduce newcomers to the tag. They contain an
>   overview of the topic defined by the tag, along with guidelines on its
>   usage.
>
> All registered users may propose new tag wikis.
>
> (Note that if you have less than 2000 reputation, your tag wiki will
>   be peer reviewed before it is published.)

How do tag wikis work on private beta metas? How can we get a useful [faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) tag wiki on a private beta?

Comment: Perhaps the wiki's aren't pushed until the site hits public beta - but it does seem odd that they're not "prepushed".

Comment: @ChrisF I suspect you're right, just looking for an authoritative answer from a dev or employee.

Comment: This is not specific to private betas: all 2.0 sites were affected until a few hours ago. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites

Answer (score 2):

[faq-proposed](/questions/tagged/faq-proposed) is not in [the list of tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66425/can-the-tag-wikis-for-the-mandatory-tags-and-moderator-only-tags-be-propagated-t/66635#66635) that were asked to be synced that led to this functionality in the first place, so my assumption is that tags outside of this predefined list are not synced between Meta and the per-site metas.

Since you can also not create tag wikis on per-site metas, you'll note that most tag wikis on per-site metas are blank across the network. There are some exceptions to this, as can [be seen on Gaming's meta](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/tags), but as evidenced by the wiki history this is either currently a moderator-only functionality, or simply occurred before this restriction was put into place. Based on [a related bug report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/121020/cant-create-a-new-tag-wiki-se-2-0-meta-sites), I'm going to guess the former, although until that's fixed I suppose it doesn't make much difference.

If the syncing is indeed restricted to that specific list of tags, it would probably be sensible to allow meta tag wikis to be created at-will for everything else...and you [should now be able to](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites/121066#121066) edit not only those, but also the ones from the list.