# Can't create a new tag wiki SE 2.0 meta sites

Tags: bug, tag-wiki, per-site-meta

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Proposing tag wiki creation does not work on meta sites](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites)

Looks like creating tag wikis on SE 2.0 metas isn't working.

To reproduce, go to the ["moderation" tag page](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/moderation) on Programmers meta. There is no tag wiki, so click the "help us create it" link.

Instead of going to the edit page with textboxes for the excerpt and the body, another page is shown with a <kbd>Create Tag Wiki</kbd> button:

[image]

Clicking this button does nothing.

Comment: possible duplicate: [Proposing tag wiki creation does not work on meta sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/92219/154510)

Comment: @MatthewRead Oh, seriously? Hrm. Thanks.

Comment: Don't worry, [I made the same bug report once](http://meta.literature.stackexchange.com/q/130/10) :P

Comment: Hmm, I hadn't voted to close this because I thought the fact you saw the button at all meant that the system might be trying to let you (with mod powers) create a tag wiki...but perhaps not.