# Why don't meta sites use common tag wikis for common tags?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, tags, tag-wiki

Some tags such as [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [retag-request](/questions/tagged/retag-request) have, or [should have](https://lifehacks.meta.stackexchange.com/tags/retag-request/info), the same wiki across MSE and all per-site metas.

I propose that tags can be whitelisted here on MSE to have their wikis copied to all per-site metas. This could be done either

1. By SE employees. e.g., Mr. Shog. or
2. Via voting; similar to that of synonyms. Would require 5 or 10 votes.

Comment: This should [already happen](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66425/can-the-tag-wikis-for-the-mandatory-tags-and-moderator-only-tags-be-propagated-t), for the tags listed there, though they can be [modified on a per-meta basis](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/92219/proposing-tag-wiki-creation-does-not-work-on-meta-sites/121066#121066).

Comment: Closely related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116389/synchronize-tag-wikis-across-stack-exchange-sites (only difference is main vs. meta sites)